# Update, enter and exit selections in a single chain

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using D3 to create reactive visualizations. Whenever the data changes, I find myself using this pattern a lot:

```
function redraw(myData) {
    // if data points decreased, remove some rectangles
    d3.selectAll('rect')
        .data(myData)
        .exit()
        .remove();
    // if data points increased, add some rectangles
    d3.selectAll('rect')
        .data(myData)
        .enter()
        .append('rect');
    // assign attribute values to all rectangles
    d3.selectAll('rect')
        .data(myData)
        .attr('width', (d) => d.width)
        .attr('height', (d) => d.height)
        .attr('fill', 'blue');
}
```

Is there a way to shorten this operation to a single long chain of operations?

I've seen many D3 examples like [this](https://beta.observablehq.com/@mbostock/d3-bar-chart) which are fine for a one-time draw. I couldn't get them to work for redraws.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The join() method

You asked...

> Is there a way to shorten this operation to a **single long chain** of operations? (emphasis mine)

Yes, there is: if you're using D3 v5.8 or above you can take advantage of the new method [`selection.join()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_join) to make a single chain with the `update`, `enter` and `exit` selections. By the way the example you linked (made by Bostock, D3 creator) is already using `join()`, so it's not *"for a one-time draw"* as you said.

Your whole function would be:

```
function redraw(myData) {
    d3.select(foo).selectAll('rect')
        .data(myData)
        .join('rect')
        .attr('width', (d) => d.width)
        .attr('height', (d) => d.height)
        .attr('fill', 'blue');
};
```

Here is a basic demo:

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg");

d3.interval(function() {
  redraw(getData());
}, 1500);

redraw(getData());

function redraw(myData) {
  svg.selectAll('rect')
    .data(myData)
    .join('rect')
    .attr('width', (d) => d.width)
    .attr('height', (d) => d.height)
    .attr('x', (d) => d.x)
    .attr('y', (d) => d.y)
    .style('fill', 'lavender')
    .style('stroke', '#444');
};

function getData() {
  return d3.range(~~(Math.random() * 20)).map(function(d) {
    return {
      x: Math.random() * 250,
      y: Math.random() * 100,
      width: 10 + Math.random() * 40,
      height: 10 + Math.random() * 40,
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

---

**PS**: your current function has some problems. First, `d3.selectAll` is not the same of `selection.selectAll` (pay attention to `d3.select(foo)` in my function). Second, you don't have the correct `update`, `enter` and `exit` selections in that function. Have a look [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218) for the idiomatic pattern.